# Getting Null response while hitting https URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection

Am facing some issue while hitting https url in objective C.Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY URL",uid];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSUInteger responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [self.responseData setLength:0];

    NSLog(@"connection");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [_responseData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"_responseData%@",_responseData);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *jError;
   NSArray *myApps= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jError];
    NSLog(@"jError:%@",jError);
}
```

When i run the app in simulator,sometimes am getting the **myApps** value.
But most of the time am not getting the response.At that time am able to see the value of **_responseData** and **myApps** as empty.Getting responseData like this

> _responseData<3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c3e0a 3c212d2d 20242052 65766973 696f6e3a 20322e31 34303431 36202420 2d2d3e0a 3c212d2d
>   5b696620 49454d6f>

And error like this.myApps is empty

> jError:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.}

When i get this error I tried hitting the URL in browser am getting the response in browser.
So i clean and run the app once again,still am facing the same issue.
But if change the simulator for example am running in iPhone 6s and getting above error and now change to iPhone 6 than am getting the response.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: In `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, convert `_responseData` to an `NSString` and see what you have.

Comment: I tried like NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; .But am getting the response in <html> tag format like  this                                                                                       <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/cdc/clientlibs/responsive/js/login.js"></script> 

  <!--[if IE 8]></ie><![endif]-->


  </body>
  </html>

Comment: The response is not JSON (from the sample you gave, it's not complete by the way, but i starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>`), that's why you get the error when you try with `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to handle cookies in improper way. Remove below line from your code and check.

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
```

Comment: I tried this and run in the same simulator but still am getting null response  :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, apostrophe ('), space or some special characters may cause the NSMutableURLRequest to return a "null" URL.
Encode (percent escape encoding) the string url before passing it to the NSMutableURLRequest like this:

```
NSString *updatedPhotoUrl     = originalUrlString ;

updatedPhotoUrl               = [updatedPhotoUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: updatedPhotoUrl]];
```